# variable check in a thread get incorrectly optimized when compiled in msvc

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

std::mutex ll;

void f2()
{
    thread_local static bool tag = false;
    while (1)
    {
        if (tag)
        {
            ll.lock();
            ll.unlock();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t{ f2 };
    t.join();
}
```

When I compile the above code with -O2 in msvc(vs 2019), the "tag" get optimized。And you can successfully breakpoint at line "ll.lock()" while running the above code. While it should not step into the ll.lock(),ll.unlock() section.

In gcc/clang, you can see load/compare instruction of tag in the Assembly Code.

Why? Is this a bug of msvc compiler?

Edit:
I tested more codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

std::mutex ll;

void f3()
{
    thread_local static int tag = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (tag)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uni_lock(ll);
            cout << tag << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t{ f3 };
    t.join();
}
```

If it's "inifinite loop without side-effects" problems, cout here has side-effects, there should'nt be any prints.But the program print out zeroes when executed.

How to explain this?

Comment: This program looks UB to me. You have an infinite loop that doesn't make progress. This loop is UB. `thread_local` objects are normally invisible from outside; the only time you modified `tag` was its initialization, and no references are delivered to other threads, so I'd be quite surprised if it didn't get optimized in a release build. As a result, the condition inside the loop is always false, and can be totally eliminated and you'll be left with an empty infinite loop - which is UB.

Comment: The thing you are seeing is totally unrelated to thread_local. Your loop in f2 has no observable side effects. Which is as stated undefined behavior. This rule was added to the C++ standards so compilers can actually optimize code.

Comment: well, I removed threadlocal here. so the problem is while(1) is ub here?

Comment: "Infinite loop without side-effects" is one of the examples of undefined behavior listed on: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: "you can see load/compare instruction" [I cannot](https://godbolt.org/z/PxesK1hqP)

Comment: your argument about the second example is flawed. If the code would do what you expect (not take the `if` branch, because `tag` is `0`) then it would be an infiinite loop without side effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, it is a infinite loop without side effects UB.